# Hide overflow flutter, without overflowed message

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an animation that I want to be partially visible.

[image]

Basically the end of the screen should cut the animation in half. So the animation is overflowing but that's intended. How do I remove the overflowed message then ?

```
return ClipRect(
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 32,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(spacingM, spacingM, 0, spacingM),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          TextInfo(
              location: location, dateFormatter: dateFormatter, date: date),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(30, 0),
            child: WeatherAnimation(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using wrapping what is overflowing with a [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html). This will clip out what is overflowing.

**In this scenario**, I believe you should wrap the `Padding` widget or perhaps the `Row` widget with `FittedBox` which would allow the `FittedBox` to take shape of its parent and clip the children to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ClipRect, you can use Stack with fit as StackFit.expand.

```
return Stack(
fit: StackFit.expand,
  children: [ 
  Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 32,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(spacingM, spacingM, 0, spacingM),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          TextInfo(
              location: location, dateFormatter: dateFormatter, date: date),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(30, 0),
            child: WeatherAnimation(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
 ]
);
```

let me know, if this work.